# count number of elements in a CSV in a row in Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv, foreach

I have the following piece of code to process a CSV:

```
CSV.foreach("./matrix1.csv") do |row|
 puts "Row is: " 
 print row
 line_count += 1
end
```

And it successfully found out the number of line in the CSV. However, how can I find the number of CSV elements in one line(row).
For example, I have the following CSV

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

How can I see that the number of elements is 5?

Comment: `row.size` / `row.length` should work.

Comment: @Stefan a violent paranoid living inside me says it should be `CSV.foreach(...).max_by(&:size).size` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each line contains same number of elements then:

```
CSV.open('test.csv', 'r') { |csv| puts csv.first.length }
```

If not then count for each line:

```
CSV.foreach('test.csv', 'r') { |row| puts r.length }
```

Comment: or `CSV.foreach('test.csv','r').max_by(&:length).length` for the longest row

Answer (score 0):

```
row.size
```

worked as suggested by @Stefan

But a more error prone approach is:

```
CSV.foreach('test.csv','r').max_by(&:length).length
```

Another way is to get the size of the current line:

```
CSV.foreach('test.csv', 'r') { |row| puts r.length }
```